# How to get user details using BadgeVille API?

Tags: php, javascript, badge

How can I get current user's details with BadgeVille API?
I want to fetch user's total points, the level image etc.
Anyone with BadgeVille experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual I have found the answer by myself. Here is how you can do this:

```
console.log(Badgeville.Settings.user)
```